# How to [self addsubview:view] remove or go back other subview

Tags: ios, xcode

This is my code about subviews. I make one self addSubview and I have no idea to delete this subview. Any ideas? I search for 2 hours and using removefromsuperview and it was not worked.

One more thing is I want to make this self addSubview is below the keypop Subview. please help me thanks

```
    [self addSubview:FBW];

    [text setText:b.titleLabel.text];
    [keyPop addSubview:text];
    [b addSubview:keyPop];
```

I will tell you how my view looks like. b - button is the first view, in here, I declared self addsubview FBW(because I don't want to move my FBW view according to b mother view) and b buttons have keypop. keypops have text for subview. I want to make this FBW view below keypad. So I use [b insertSubview:keypop belowSubview:FBW] but it is not working. any suggestions?

Below is my structure.

b - (UIButton) - keypop (UIImageview) - text (UILABEL)//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
b - (UIButton) - self addsubview (UILABEL)

Comment: Your question is not understandable. Make it clear

Comment: [FBW removeFromSuperview]; Use this. In place of FBW you can use ur subview name.

Comment: I edited my post please help me more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to call
`[FBW removeFromSuperview]`.

To move one subview underneath another, call
`[self insertSubview:FBW belowSubview:b]`

Or alternatively, call this when you added the second view:

`[self bringSubviewToFront:b]`

Comment: Great insertSubview:A belowSubview:B is not working I will tell you how my view looks like. b - button is the first view, in here, I declared self addsubview FBW(because I don't want to move my FBW view according to b mother view) and b buttons have keypop. keypops have text for subview. I want to make this FBW view below keypad. So I use [b insertSubview:keypop belowSubview:FBW] but it is not working. any suggestions?